# Is there a way to calculate how many bytes a register is holding by using NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Suppose that register EAX is only holding the character 'a', so AL would be holding 61 (this number is in hexadecimal, 61 is ASCII value for 'a'). Is there a way to use NASM to know that EAX is only holding 1 byte of data? I want to store this number in another register, say EBX, and do something like

`cmp EBX, 1
je do_something_if_EAX_has_1_byte`

EDIT: As stated in one of the answers, a better name for my question is:  "how do I find out if the value stored by EAX is representable using 1 byte?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each register has a fixed size, irrespective of what you store in it.

From your question it looks like you're interested in the answer to a different question: "*how do I find out if the value stored by EAX is representable using 1 byte*". If that is indeed the case, all you have to do is compare EAX with the maximum number that fits in one byte.

Answer (score 3):

You can scan the leading digit with [Bit Scan Reverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) instruction and use linear algebra to map the output in between 0..31 to range 0..4. Special care has to be applied for the case when the operand is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Zero it out before using it, then check the size using a bitmask or a compare.

```
xor eax, eax ; clear it
mov eax, whatever
cmp eax, 255
jle eax_has_one_byte ; if it is less than or equal to 255, it uses one byte
cmp eax, 65535
jle eax_has_two_bytes
```

and so on.